# ES6 understand some annotations <T>, <

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I, i'm working  in  new project with JSX, ES6 and react . In a file component i found this declaration:

```
export default class Table<T> extends React.Component<TableProps<T>, any> {
```

I searched in http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html or other site es6, but i can not find any information. Also link to read explain is it help for me.

- `<T>` what is?
- `AAAA<BBB` what is?
- `, any >` what is?

Comment: Thats typescript not pure javascript.

Comment: I've changed some of your formatting so that the code is *visible* in your bullet points at the bottom. But I've no idea what your intent was with the second one since there's no `AAAA<BBB` visible anywhere before that point.

Comment: If you're using Babel, then this is Flowtype syntax, not Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is called generics and it is not related to ES6 or even JavaScript. Instead it is the [TypeScript Generics notation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).